# Expected amount of parts in random cut

Tags: probability

If there is a square (or circle), we cut it $i$ times in uniform random location, the cut paths are straight and in uniform random angle. Not just horizontal and vertical paths.

What is the the expected amount of the parts in $i$ times?

For example:

if $i = 1$, it has $2$ parts, so the the expected amount is $2$.

if $i = 2$, it may have $3$ parts or $4$ parts.

Is there any theory can be the solution of this problem?

I'm sorry for my poor English, so I draw 3 images to describe what I mean. Hope this can clear my question. Thank you all.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/arTSH.png

Comment: From the rest of the question, it appears that "off" is misleading and should be removed -- you're merely cutting the figure, not cutting off parts in the sense that they no longer take part in subsequent steps. Also, "cutting in uniform random location" is unclear, since a cut does not take place at a single location. Do you mean that two points are uniformly randomly chosen and the cut is along the line joining them?

Comment: I believe that the graph-theory tag is not in place here, why did you tag the question with it ?

Answer (score 0):

**This is my interpretation of the problem:** at every time you choose a random point of the figure (either a square or a circle or any convex set with positive measure) and draw a straight line by that point either horizontally or vertically with probability $\frac12$ for each case. Is this interpretation correct?

If so, at every time $i$ the probability to randomly choose a point lying in one of the previous lines is null. Therefore the lines up to time $i$ altogether form an $m\times n$ grid with $m+n=i+2$. Note that an $m\times n$ grid splits the figure in $mn=m(i+2-m)$ parts.

If $a_i$ denotes the number $m$ of rows in the grid, then
$$
\mathbb P(a_i=m) ~=~ \frac{\mathbb P(a_{i-1}={m-1}) ~+~ \mathbb P(a_{i-1}=m)}{2}
$$
Indeed, at time $i$ you have $m$ rows if and only if either at time $i-1$ you had $m-1$ rows and at time $i$ you drew a horizontal line, or at time $i-1$ you had $m$ rows and at time $i$ you drew a vertical line. Both these two cases have conditional probability $\frac12$.

You can easily check by induction that
$$
\mathbb P(a_i=m) = \frac{1}{2^i}\binom{i}{m-1}
$$
so, the expected value you are looking for at time $i$ is
$$
\sum_{j=1}^i
\sum_{m=1}^{j+1}
m(j+2-m)\frac{1}{2^j}\binom{j}{m-1}
$$

By suitably modifying and deriving the identity $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkx^k = (1+x)^n$ (and then evaluating it in $x=1$) you can end up with a closed form of the previous expression.

Comment: Nice, but the horizontal/vertical interpretation seems rather arbitrary to me.

Comment: @leonbloy I agree, this is quite a big simplification. I guess at first I misinterpreted the meaning of _straight_ line...